# Validates presence only for updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, is there a way to apply

```
validates :comment, presence: true
```

but only to Updates to that model?

I don't want comments to be required for making a New object, in fact I don't even have the form field but for Updates I want them to be compulsory. Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`on`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on):

```
validates :comment, presence: true, on: :update
```

Comment: Brilliant. I assume I can also do that with multiple actions, replacing :update with [:update, :destroy} etc? Thank you so much.

Comment: No, you can't; validation doesn't work on destroy, it only works on update and create. If you want it to happen on both actions, omit `on`  completely. `validates :comment, presence: true` validates on both create and update.

Comment: I've just found this out. Validating presence on update is causing me all kind of other trouble with my undo function. Maybe it's not the solution I need. Your answer does just what I wanted though, I just may need to look elsewhere for a way to make people comment on their updates.